# Update Matlab graphics in Overleaf

Tags: graphics, overleaf, matlab

I was told that it is possible to link a Matlab script with an Overleaf account such that output of any form (figures, tables and data) can be updated and imported everytime a Matlab script is ran.

Does anyone know how to do this, since I could not figure this out.

If not, what is generally knwon to be the best way (in terms of quality) and most efficient way (I assume just by uploading into Overleaf) to import Matlab graphics and data?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Have you asked the overleaf support for this? They should know ...

Comment: What I do is use git to sync Matlab with overleaf. A folder containing Logs of commandline outputs and files saved containing variables (tables) and figures. All of which require a certain transformation to be readable by LaTeX. Variables I export as csv with `&` as a separator and `\\` as line break. Figures I export to tikz.

Comment: I'd recommend git as suggested, or if you can put your outputs at some publicly accessible URL, you could add them to your project using this approach (directions are for Google Drive but the same approach works for any public URL): https://www.overleaf.com/learn/how-to/How_can_I_upload_files_from_Google_Drive%3F With the URL approach, you'll need to open the Overleaf project and click "Refresh" for each linked file to pull in the latest version, vs with the git integration as soon as you push the files to Overleaf (possibly with a MATLAB script) they'll be available in your Overleaf project.